# RTextTools empty document

Tags: r, text

After creating a matrix using the `create_matrix()` function in the package '`RTextTools`', I receive the following error:

```
train.matrix = create_matrix(cbind(train.corpus,train.pp.title), language="english",
weighting=weightTfIdf)
```

Warning message:

```
In weighting(x) :
  empty document(s):
```

I believe this may be due the `weightTfIdf` weighting requiring that all rows that are filled in the corpus.

What can I do to avoid this warning message?

Comment: a straight forward work around would be to save the matrix `cbind(train.corpus,train.pp.title)` first and check for zero rows

Comment: You're right. That sounds quite logical. I'll try that... except now I will be left with blank rows. If I were to gsub, would that also replace the spaces in the other rows?

Comment: I would do something like that `mat[rowSums(apply(mat, 2, nchar))!=0, ]`, where `mat` is your matrix..

with gsub it depends how you use it...

Comment: +1 Thanks, Holzbrn.  Your suggestions led me to a possible solution.